# Possible to use tags/buttons as exposed filters?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a page that will be a grid of a dozen content types. I would like to have a tag-like button or text link above the grid of content to allow the user to toggle / filter between what content type they wish to see. I know that exposed filters allows you to use a dropdown or auto-complete, but is this possible with tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) for converting your drop down exposed filter into links. Then you can styling your links as tags.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by adding taxonomy as filter to the View page?

Here is an article I found that introduces the procedure, https://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/taxonomy/views